# How to bypass "Illustrator Options" screen when saving a document in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When saving my work in Illustrator, I always have to click OK in some "Illustrator Options" screen. Is there a way to bypass/remove/deactivate this screen? That would save me thousands of clicks per year.

Comment: You never change the options?

Comment: Absolutely never.

Comment: Its a bit bad design the options should be visible only when invoked a bit like the extra option box in word. Adobe is quite atrocious about such things.

Comment: If you are not altering anything, hitting enter should do it.

Comment: We are talking about the file for the first time or save a copy!? Just hitting cmd-s the second time should not trigger the dialogue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way to bypass or otherwise disable the Options dialog when saving.

Comment: Simply press enter when the window pops-up.

Comment: @PeteC. that **does not** "bypass" the options, it commits to however they are set.

Comment: yes I know, but that's the quicker way to handle it.